# How to convert android project in apk without android studio

Tags: android, apk

How to convert android project to apk file without android studio using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bundle tool](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) to first create bundle and then use command line to build apk

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab -- 
output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
--ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks
--ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd
--ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias
--key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd
```

[Here is link for more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#generate_apks)